# Solution to Bulk FindAndModify in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

My use case is as follows -
I have a collection of documents in mongoDB which I have to send for analysis.
The format of the documents are as follows -

{ _id:ObjectId("517e769164702dacea7c40d8") , 
date:"1359911127494",
status:"available",
other_fields... }

I have a reader process which picks first 100 documents with *status:available* sorted by *date* and modifies them with *status:processing*.
ReaderProcess sends the documents for analysis. Once the analysis is complete the *status* is changed to *processed*.

Currently reader process first fetch 100 documents sorted by *date* and then update the *status* to *processing* for each document in a loop. Is there any better/efficient solution for this case?

Also, in future for scalability, we might go with more than one reader process.
In this case, I want that 100 documents picked by one reader process should not get picked by another reader process. But fetching and updating are seperate queries right now, so it is very much possible that multiple reader processes pick same documents.

Bulk *findAndModify* (with limit) would have solved all these problems. But unfortunately it is not provided in MongoDB yet. Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you mention there is currently no clean way to do what you want. The best approach at this time for operations like the one you need is this :

1. Reader selects X documents with appropriate limit and sorting
2. Reader marks the documents returned by 1) with it's own unique reader ID (`e.g. update({_id:{$in:[<result set ids>]}, state:"available", $isolated:1}, {$set:{readerId:<your reader's ID>, state:"processing"}}, false, true)`)
3. Reader selects all documents marked as processing and with it's own reader ID. At this point it is guaranteed that you have exclusive access to the resulting set of documents.
4. Offer the resultset from 3) for your processing.

Note that this even works in highly concurrent situations as a reader can never reserve documents not already reserved by another reader (note that step 2 can only reserve currently available documents, and writes are atomic). I would add a timestamp with reservation time as well if you want to be able to time out reservations (for example for scenarios where readers might crash/fail).

EDIT: More details :

All write operations can occasionally yield for pending operations if the write takes a relatively long time. This means that step 2) might not see all documents marked by step 1) unless you take the following steps :

- Use an appropriate "w" (write concern) value, meaning 1 or higher. This will ensure that the connection on which the write operation is invoked will wait for it to complete regardless of it yielding.
- Make sure you do the read in step 2 on the same connection (only relevant for replicasets with slaveOk enabled reads) or thread so that they are guaranteed to be sequential. The former can be done in most drivers with the "requestStart" and "requestDone" methods or similar (Java documentation [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-concurrency/)).

  - Add the $isolated flag to your multi-updates to ensure it cannot be interleaved with other write operations.

Also see comments for discussion regarding atomicity/isolation. I incorrectly assumed multi-updates were isolated. They are not, or at least not by default.

Comment: You have written writes are atomic, I am assuming write for a single document because 2nd step update with multi flag true won't be atomic unless used with isolation (only with unsharded setup). Correct me if I am wrong. Apart from that great answer.

Comment: No the entire write operation is atomic. So if you update 100 documents as I suggested that entire operation is atomic. It's sharding safe.

Comment: Are you sure MongoDB does atomic multi document updates? It is sharding safe but that's because sharding works in a particular manner, with the mongos routing operations to the appropiate mongod in the set.

Comment: I am. There can only be on concurrent write operation on a single mongod process (2.0 and earlier) or on a single db (2.2+). In this context the multi update is one write operation. So on single shard environments this update will complete in its entirety before another write operation is allowed. Note that the write can be considered atomic but large multi-write operations (multi update, large removes) will yield for *read* operations on occassion. As such you cannot count on a read operation invoked during or after a write to see those changes. That's not relevant here though.

Comment: As for a sharded environment the same applies with the small footnote that if you are running multiple mongos instances I think there can be an out-of-order problem if two updates (multi or otherwise) are invoked that update the same document(s). It cannot guarantee which is performed first.

Comment: @RemonvanVliet I thought you needed to use the [`$isolated`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/isolated/#op._S_isolated) operator to ensure a multi-update was not interleaved with other writes.

Comment: I agree with @JohnnyHK `mongod` can subside if the data is not in RAM to continue the other write operations as such a multi document update is not isolated, nor is it a all or nothing atomic operation, mongodb only provides that level of atomicity on a single document level.

Comment: Though come to think of it, I haven't looked at the source code for the lock subsider so I am unsure what operation it will pick when information isn't in RAM...

Comment: There is a note given in MongoDB manual for db.collection.update() [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) The multi update operation may interleave with other write operations. For unsharded collections, you can override this behavior with the $isolated isolation operator, which isolates the update operation and blocks other write operations during the update.

Comment: I stand corrected. "Atomic" wasn't the appropriate term to begin with but I did think the write operations were all isolated. I see that 10gen also continued it's tradition to make the least obvious/most risky value for a flag the default. I'll adjust my answer accordingly. I don't think it really affects the suggested implementation as even interleaved updated on the same data will still result in individual documents being reserved for a single reader.

Comment: Couldn't you drop the "state" altogether and just query for {_id:{$in:[<result set ids>]}, readerID: null, $isolated:1} in step 2?

Comment: You could but this was part of the OP requirements.